# Proof Of De Morgan`s Laws with indexed set and a universal set.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, intuition

Let $E$ be a universal set and $\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J},$ for some index set $J$ be a family of subsets of $E.$

Prove that:
(a)$E-\bigcup_{\alpha \in J}A_{\alpha} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in J}($R$-A_{\alpha}).$

I do not know what is $R$ or it is a mistake in the question, Could anyone help me ?

(b)$E-\bigcap_{\alpha \in J}A_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}($E$-A_{\alpha}).$

Shall I prove it by induction? but what about the index set is it countably infinite or finite or uncountable, and how the proof will differ?

Comment: I think the $R$ is just a typo. On many keyboard layouts, $R$ is right next to $E$ after all.

Comment: @DanielFischer I left a comment just here yesterday, but there is not now. Can a moderator delete a comment which doesn't like or can be delete by others. I'm curious about it?

Comment: @MyGlasses Comments can be deleted by their authors, by moderators, or via flags. If a comment is flagged $n$ times (where $n$ depends on the number of upvotes on the comment, but also on the contents; if a comment contains some particular words or phrases, a single flag suffices to delete it) it is deleted by the system. Most comment-deletions by moderators are in response to flags, and when a comment on a page is flagged, we often take a look at the rest of the page to see whether there are further comments that should be deleted. That seems to have happened here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever $R$ means should have been identified earlier in your reference book, otherwise it is a mystery.

As to the second, just use the definitions that $$\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}  X_\alpha := \{x~:~ \exists \alpha \in J~ (x\in X_\alpha)\} = \{x~:~\bigvee_{\alpha\in J}(x\in X_\alpha)\}\\ \bigcap_{\alpha\in J} X_\alpha := \{x~:~ \forall \alpha\in J~(x\in X_\alpha)\}=\{x~:~ \bigwedge_{\alpha\in J}(x\in X_\alpha)\}\\ B- A = \{x ~:~ x \in B~\wedge~ x\notin A\}$$

Comment: My reference is Bartle & Sherbert. This is a question from my professor not from the book..... what about the index set?

Answer (score 2):

‎\begin{eqnarray*}‎
‎(\bigcap_{i\in\Lambda}A_i)^c &=& \{x|x\notin \bigcap_{i\in\Lambda}A_i\} \\‎
                             ‎&=& \{x|\exists i\in\Lambda,~~x\notin A_i\}\\‎
                             ‎&=& \{x|\exists i\in\Lambda,~~x\in A_i^c\} \\‎
                             ‎&=& \bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}A_i^c‎               
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}‎
‎(\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}A_i)^c &=& \{x|x\notin \bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}A_i\} \\‎
                             ‎&=& \{x|\forall i\in\Lambda,~~x\notin A_i\}\\‎
                             ‎&=& \{x|\forall i\in\Lambda,~~x\in A_i^c\} \\‎
                             ‎&=& \bigcap_{i\in\Lambda}A_i^c‎               
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎

Comment: +1. nice and complete.